# Is it possible to get the index of the element that I dragged over?

Tags: angularjs, html

I am using [angular-dragdrop](http://angular-dragdrop.github.io/angular-dragdrop). What I need is to insert the dragged item in the correct place in the list I am dragging over. When the drop happens I get:

```
 $scope.onDrop = function ($event, $data, array) {
        // $data is the object being dropped.   
        array.push({
            id: $data.id,
            text: $data.text
        });
    };
```

and as you can see I am just adding to the end of the array.
If I had an index, then I can insert it where it was dropped.

Is this possible with the component?

Comment: If you create a plunker with the code you are working with, that would help troubleshoot.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am basically using : http://angular-dragdrop.github.io/angular-dragdrop/examples/.

Comment: The `$event` object has a `.toElement` property. If your `<li>`'s all have unique id attributes you could figure out which `<li>` it was dropped on, look it up in the array, and put the dropped item in the array after it.

Comment: Okay, I have taken what Lex mentioned and find a $event.target element and put an id on this. Thanks that worked. Can you put that as the answer. Thank you to all for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after. Basically, it captures the event, and finds the index of the target object's text in the array, and then inserts there.

```
  $scope.onDrop = function($event,$data,array){

      var idx = array.indexOf($event.target.innerText);

      array.splice(idx, 0, $data);

      $log.debug('Dropped ' + $data + ' on ' + $event.target.innerText);
      console.warn(array);
  };
```

Plunker with positioning: http://plnkr.co/edit/tNmVIj4YY76OrOiNiWf0?p=preview

Old plunker (sans positioning): http://plnkr.co/edit/5fD4UJA4y2sdZig2Rxtq?p=preview

Comment: Thank you Brian (I've never created a plunkr before but will do now in the future). So in your plunkr if I drag 'Jane' above 'Jack' I want the index of Jack in the list so that I can insert above him.

Comment: Ohh, ok. I see where you are going with this now. Let me think on this